# Trying to use onnxruntime with GPU. SessionOptionsAppendExecutionProvider_CUDA gives error

Tags: cuda, onnxruntime

I'm learning onnxruntime inferencing with GPU. I got the code from https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-inference-examples.git.
I tried the case main/c_cxx/fns_candy_style_transfer. Follow instructions in https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-inference-examples/tree/main/c_cxx.

When calling `OrtStatus* onnx_status = g_ort->SessionOptionsAppendExecutionProvider_CUDA(session_options, &o);`, I get the following error:

```
Try to enable CUDA first
D:\a\_work\1\s\onnxruntime\core\session\provider_bridge_ort.cc:1106 onnxruntime::ProviderLibrary::Get [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : LoadLibrary failed with error 126 "" when trying to load "D:\Work\SystemVue\6G\AL\ONNX\c_cxx\cudabuild\fns_candy_style_transfer\Debug\onnxruntime_providers_cuda.dll"

CUDA is not available
```

I use Windows10, Visual Studio 2022.
My GPU is NVIDIA RTX A2000.
I installed the latest CUDA Toolkit V12.1 and cuDNN and set environment variables for them by following instructions in CUDA section of https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/build/eps.html#cuda.

How can I make CUDA available in order to run the example?

Answer (score 1):

You must use CUDA 11.6, CUDA 12.1 is too recent

Answer (score 0):

Yes for prebuilt binaries you will have to use CUDA<12.0, furthermore you also have to have cuDNN 8.X binaries on your PATH.

Besides that I would recommend using the newer api (V2) to set provider options. You can find a sample usage [here](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/CUDA-ExecutionProvider.html#cc).